# array push of records obtained from mongo db

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

In `MEAN` stack, I am trying to store the records obtained from mongo db in an array, but I am not able to store the record in an array.

This is my code, I am trying to push the records obtained from projectimage to fulldetails[] array, but it failed. Suggest me the possible solution to store the mongo db records to array

```
    var express = require("express"),
     router = express.Router(),
     project = require("../../models/project.js"),
     projectimage = require("../../models/projectimages.js"),

             var details=data;
                 var fulldetails=[];

for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
    var prjct_id=details[i]._id;
    console.log('below'+i);
    fulldetails.push(details[i]);
    projectimage.findOne({projectId: prjct_id}, function(err, data){
       fulldetails.concat(data);
                   });
    console.log(fulldetails);
       return false;    
}
```

Comment: You have to set the `fullDetails` to the document it belong and use `save()` on the document to persist in database. If it is `project` then `find` project document  and  something like `project.fullDetails = fullDetails` and then `project.save()`.

Comment: Where are you checking `fulldetails` array i.e. how are you saying your array is empty? Please share rest of of the code.

Comment: @Veeram, that's not what he means I think. He just wants to push data into an array and see it there at the end. Probably checking `fullDetails` before all find calls are returned.

Comment: @TalhaAwan You are right. I misread the post. @vimal kumar How is `details` created ? and may be verify you're sending the right values to the find method.

Comment: Can you provide any error detail ?

Comment: yes i need to push the data inside the full details array and need to see the all the data in the full details array i have tried array push but it doesn't work @v

Answer (score 0):

I think what do you want is to get an array from your Mongo collection, correct me if I am wrong.

I am also assuming that Mongo query runs successfully, and returns the records correctly. then you can use `toArray` function to get array in callback.

```
// let's say Furniture is your collection
let furniture = Furniture.find({});
let details = [];
furniture.toArray((err, array) => {
  if (err) return; 
  details = array; // now details has your collections' documents
});
```

For more refer [this](http://www.collectionsjs.com/method/to-array)

Let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get a flat array of full details. If my assumption is correct, you could try my solution here:

```
var fulldetails=[];

for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {

    var prjct_id=details[i]._id;

    projectimage.find({projectId: prjct_id}).toArray(function(err, data){ //convert data to array first
        console.log(data);
        fulldetails.concat(data); // concat data to fulldetails to get a flat array
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but the data is not inserted into fulldetails array i have posted the code which i tried

Comment: I saw you were missing the toArray function as shown in my code right after the find query. It's important because the returned data is cursor type not array without it.